# filenames to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

```
#get filenames from txtfile
foreach ($file in Get-Content -Path "C:\Filelist.txt") 
{
#Remove : and replace with Underscores
    $name = ( $file) -replace '\\', '_' -replace ':'
#Create new folder at destination location with new filename
    New-Item -Path "\\destinationpc\$name" -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    
###Next step How would one create a csv with 2 columns, the original name and new name?
      
}
```

Next step I'm having difficulty with is- How would one create a csv with 2 columns, the original name and new name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Content C:\Filelist.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_ -replace '\\', '_' -replace ':'
    # Create new folder at destination location with new filename
    New-Item -Path "\\destinationpc\$name" -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

    # Output an object with properties reflecting the original and the new name
    [pscustomobject] @{
      OriginalName = $_
      NewName = $name
    }

  } |
    Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
```

<sup>Note: In PowerShell [Core] **v6+**, both `-NoTypeInformation` and `-Encoding utf8` are *implied*; in *Windows PowerShell*, the default character encoding is ASCII(!), and `utf8` invariably creates a UTF-8 file *with a BOM*.</sup>